# Any performance advantage of jQuery ajax load() vs get()?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Consider the following jQuery ajax request syntaxes:

Pattern A:

```
$('#mywrap').load('path/to/file.html #specialdiv');
```

Pattern B:

```
$.get('path/to/file.html', function(responseText){
    $('#mywrap').html( $(responseText).find('#specialdiv').text() );
});
```

Now, these two patterns should do basically the same job. Again, there's no doubt about which pattern is the winner for brevity!

Now my question is this: Is there any *performance* or other advantage to using the first pattern? In other words, when I use `.load()`, is it essentially doing (under the hood) exactly what the `$.get()` pattern is doing explicitly in Pattern B?

Comment: Open your dev console, turn on the profiler, run both codes, then check.

Comment: JQuery is open source, as such you can see the inner code in `load`, I encourage you to check it out and report back if you see anything that would lead to to believe that there would be a difference in performance.

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that, but [`load()` is implemented in terms of `ajax()`, yes.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/load.js)

Comment: both `load()` and `$.get` are just shortcuts for `$.ajax`, which in turn is a shortcut for `XMLHttpRequest`, they all do the same thing. And yes, `load()` just inserts the result the exact same way you're doing in the callback for `$.get`, it's just a shortcut.

Comment: Thanks guys for weighing in. @FrédéricHamidi: Thanks for the link into the "belly" of `.load()` it did throw some light on this matter for me.

Comment: @adeneo: I appreciate your input. Thank you for actually answering the question for me directly, though as a comment.

Comment: Now to all of you: Is it because the question is too plain basic? Why isn't anybody actually posting an answer *per se*?

Comment: Good question, it didn't really think of it as an answer, just a short comment, but why not dig through the source for jQuery and post a detailed answer as to what actually happens under the hood yourself.